# Java Spring Boot Web App(hello world) building with Maven fails to start Tomcat when running

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, tomcat

I am attempting to run a fresh Java Spring web app building with maven and deploying to Tomcat. I have found extensive questions on SO with similar error messages but no answer has helped. This is for a class assignment, however I can't even start since I haven't been able to boot up my tomcat server. Here is my log:

```
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.3.RELEASE)

2018-10-13 22:30:45.669  INFO 14840 --- [           main] com.store.app.Application                : 
2018-10-13 22:30:45.672  INFO 14840 --- [           main] com.store.app.Application                : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-10-13 22:30:45.778  INFO 14840 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@4fe767f3: startup date [Sat Oct 13 22:30:45 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-10-13 22:30:47.046  INFO 14840 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-10-13 22:30:47.062  INFO 14840 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-10-13 22:30:47.063  INFO 14840 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
2018-10-13 22:30:47.065  INFO 14840 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [removed due to personal info]
2018-10-13 22:30:47.135 ERROR 14840 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:370) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:107) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:413) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) [spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.store.app.Application.main(Application.java:30) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:179) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5019) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    ... 39 common frames omitted

2018-10-13 22:30:47.139 ERROR 14840 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:370) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:107) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:413) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) [spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.store.app.Application.main(Application.java:30) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:960) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:179) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5019) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    ... 39 common frames omitted

2018-10-13 22:30:47.141  INFO 14840 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-10-13 22:30:47.142  WARN 14840 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2018-10-13 22:30:47.148  INFO 14840 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-10-13 22:30:47.154 ERROR 14840 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.store.app.Application.main(Application.java:30) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:413) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:960) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:370) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:107) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:960) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:179) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5019) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

Shortened error without tomcat vesion in pom.xml:

```
ERROR 15272 --- [cat-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
```

As you can see, it is failing to start the embedded tomcat component. Here are my relevant files.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.store.rest</groupId>
<artifactId>store</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <tomcat.version>9.0.12</tomcat.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20170516</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

My web.xml has the following servlets:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
             <param-value>com.store.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/store/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Only real change I have made is the class declaration in Application.java

```
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements CommandLineRunner {
```

because that seems to be needed. Although I'm not sure about anything anymore.

I have Tomcat 9.0.12 installed and am using IntelliJ IDE. I have Java V8 Update 161 installed (build 1.8.0_161). Thank you in advance.

Comment: Remove `tomcat.version`, remove `javax.servlet-api` dependency, remove `spring-web` dependency. Remove the `web.xml`. And don't extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` (the latter is only needed if you want to deploy the application`. If you want to use jersey then use the Spring Managed version not include and old version.

Comment: Wow thank you so much @M.Deinum, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<tomcat.version>9.0.12</tomcat.version>` from pom.xml and try.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I get a similar error, here is the start:    ERROR 15272 --- [cat-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]... Going to shorten the error because it's going to look awful in a comment.

Comment: Did you do a clean and build after removing it from pom.xml? Once you do a clean and build, what version of tomcat is being shown in the maven downloaded dependencies list on your IDE?

Comment: after rebuilding and running, it looks like it's looking for a [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31] now instead of the 9.0.12 version I have installed. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add tomcat dependency to order to deploy war..

   ```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
     <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. remove `<tomcat.version>9.0.12</tomcat.version>` does not required.
3. Clean your project by running `mvn clean install`

if still issue in conflicting embedded tomcat jar then exclude tomcat from web too.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```